# Oracle XE, count and display different combinations of rows based on one column

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations, permutation

need help with a complicated query. This is an extract from my table:

```
USERID    SERVICE
1         A
1         B
2         A
3         A
3         B
4         A
4         C
5         A
6         A
7         A
7         B
```

Ok, I would like the query to return and display all possible combinations that exist in my table with their respective counts based on the SERVICE column. For example first user has A and B service, this is one combination which occurred once. Next user has only service A, this is one more combination which occurred once. Third user has service A and B, this has happened once already and the count for this combination is 2 now, etc. So my output based on this particular input would be a table like this:

```
A  AB  AC  ABC  B  BC
3  3   1   0    0  0
```

So to clarify a bit more, if there are 3 services, then there is 3! possible combinations; 3x2x1=6 and they are A, B, C, AB, AC, BC and ABC. And my table should contain count of users which have these combination of services assigned to them.

I have tried building a matrix using this query and then getting all counts using the CUBE function:

```
select service_A, service_B, service_C from 
  (select USERID,
  max(case when SERVICE =A then 1 else null end) service_A,
  max(case when SERVICE =B then 1 else null end) service_B,
  max(case when SERVICE =C then 1 else null end) service_C
  from SOME_TABLE) 
group by CUBE(service_A, service_B,service_C);
```

But I don't get the count of all combinations. I need only combinations which happened, so counts 0 are not necessary but it is ok to display them. Thanks.

Comment: Have you a set of possible combinations? that is, do you know in advance how many columns will your query return? If not, you can not do it with a simple query, but you need something dynamic ( and then it can be hard to handle a result set with an unknown number of columns)

Comment: I know which services are available, for example there are 10 services which a person can have. So it is possible to make the calculation and find that there are 10! number of different combination of services, which is a huge number. So this would be the max number of columns. But most of them will have count 0, the problem is I don't know which ones so I need to calculate all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't output it as dynamic columns (it is difficult to do without using PL/SQL and dynamic SQL) but output it as rows instead (if you have a front-end then it can usually translate rows to columns much easier than oracle can):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table ( USERID, SERVICE ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'B' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT service,
       COUNT( userid ) AS num_users
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         LISTAGG( service ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY service ) AS service
  FROM   some_table
  GROUP BY userid
)
GROUP BY service;
```

**Output**:

```
SERVICE  NUM_USERS
------- ----------
AC               1 
A                3 
AB               3
```

**PL/SQL for dynamic columns**:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  TYPE string_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
  TYPE int_table IS TABLE OF INT;
  t_services string_table;
  t_counts   int_table;
  p_sql      CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT service,
         COUNT( userid ) AS num_users
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_services, t_counts
  FROM   (
    SELECT userid,
           CAST( LISTAGG( service ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY service ) AS VARCHAR2(2) ) AS service
    FROM   some_table
    GROUP BY userid
  )
  GROUP BY service;

  p_sql := EMPTY_CLOB() || 'SELECT ';
  p_sql := p_sql || t_counts(1) || ' AS "' || t_services(1) || '"';
  FOR i IN 2 .. t_services.COUNT LOOP
    p_sql := p_sql || ', ' || t_counts(i) || ' AS "' || t_services(i) || '"';
  END LOOP;
  p_sql := p_sql || ' FROM DUAL';

  OPEN :cur FOR p_sql;
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

**Output**:

```
AC  A   AB
--- --- ---
1   3   3
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast and accurate reply, this is exactly what I wanted!!!!